# How to access Redis results from html template in Go

Tags: templates, go, redis

I have the function

```
func front(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  posts, _ := client.HGet("post:1", "title")
  tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index", posts)
}
```

a log println shows that there are results indeed

```
2014/06/04 21:44:23 [title test_title content this is a test content]
```

but I can't get it to show on the "index" template..

the "index" template is like following

```
{{define "index"}}
<p>{{.Posts}}</p>
{{end}}
```

My problem is that {{.Posts}} shows nothing. but it should show something like `test_title content this is a test content`

What I want is to access Redis results from html template.

Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass Redis HGet to Go html template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046613/pass-redis-hget-to-go-html-template)

Comment: why did you repost the question ?

Comment: @fabrizioM Sorry i was going to delete the other and repost with a better explanation but my pc shut off in the process .. is it more understandable now?

Comment: I couldn't edit the post because it got trapped in some network issue block, but im using gosexy-redis but any Redis client is welcome if it makes life easier

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the *Posts* variable from the Template, like this:

```
{{define "index"}}
<p>{{.}}</p>
{{end}}
```

This should work. Post does not seem to be a member of the "posts" var in the go-file.